# Calculate value based on previous and current row values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm calculating accounts data where the value can obtain by current row values and previous row values.
My problem was I have to arrive two columns where both the columns are inter linked and both columns where obtain by current row values and previous row values.

My sample data

```
create Table Accounts (SNo int,Groups varchar(10),ToCollect int,Collected int)

insert into Accounts values(1,  'A',    4748,   4650)
insert into Accounts values(2,  'A',    4643,   4582)
insert into Accounts values(3,  'A',    4582,   4482)
insert into Accounts values(4,  'A',    4482,   4415)
insert into Accounts values(5,  'A',    4415,   4330)
insert into Accounts values(6,  'A',    4332,   4241)
insert into Accounts values(7,  'A',    4241,   2246)
insert into Accounts values(8,  'A',    4166,   6000)
insert into Accounts values(9,  'A',    4080,   0)
```

Tried query:

```
Select *,case when ToCollect>Collected then Collected Else ToCollect End Adjusted 
    ,case when Collected>ToCollect then Collected-ToCollect Else 0 End Excess into #1
from Accounts

select a.SNo,a.Groups,a.ToCollect,a.Collected
    ,case when a.ToCollect>(a.Collected+b.Excess) then a.Collected+b.Excess Else a.ToCollect End Adjusted 
    ,case when a.Collected+b.Excess>a.ToCollect then a.Collected+b.Adjusted-a.ToCollect Else 0 End Excess
from #1 a left join #1 b on a.SNo=b.SNo-1
```

Actual Result:

```
SNo Groups  ToCollect   Collected   Adjusted    Excess
1     A       4748        4650         4650       0
2     A       4643        4582         4582       0
3     A       4582        4482         4482       0
4     A       4482        4415         4415       0
5     A       4415        4330         4330       0
6     A       4332        4241         4241       0
7     A       4241        2246         4080       0
8     A       4166        6000         4166      1834
9     A       4080         0           4080        0
```

Expected Result:

```
 SNo    Groups  ToCollect   Collected   Adjusted    Balance Excess
  1       A       4748        4650        4650        98      0
  2       A       4643        4582        4582        61      0
  3       A       4582        4482        4482        100     0
  4       A       4482        4415        4415        67      0
  5       A       4415        4330        4330        85      0
  6       A       4332        4241        4241        91      0
  7       A       4241        2246        2246        1995    0
  8       A       4166        6000        4166        0       1834
  9       A       4080         0          1834        2246    0
```

Comment: Do you to check for Excess amount is available then take is as Adjusted amout?

Comment: I don't get it - what is the excess and why is it 0 for all rows until row 8.

Comment: Where do the values for `Adjsuted`, `Balance` and `Excess` come from on `Sno` 9? All the other follow a pattern, apart from that one.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's the only row where `Collected > ToCollect`.

Comment: @lamu perhaps the balance column should be shortfall?

Comment: Excess amount is collected - ToCollect

Comment: Excess amount is collected - ToCollect in 8th row. For 9th row 8th row excess should be added with 9th row collected

Answer (score 1):

This gets the results the OP wants, but no idea if this is *really* the correct answer:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT A.SNo,
           A.Groups,
           A.ToCollect,
           A.Collected,
           CASE WHEN A.ToCollect > A.Collected THEN A.Collected ELSE A.ToCollect END AS Adjusted,
           CASE WHEN A.ToCollect > A.Collected THEN A.ToCollect - A.Collected ELSE 0 END AS Balance,
           CASE WHEN A.ToCollect < A.Collected THEN A.Collected - A.ToCollect  ELSE 0 END AS Excess,
           SUM(CASE WHEN A.ToCollect < A.Collected THEN A.Collected - A.ToCollect  ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY SNo ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS RunningExcess      
    FROM dbo.Accounts A)
SELECT C.SNo,
       C.Groups,
       C.ToCollect,
       C.Collected,
       ISNULL(NULLIF(C.RunningExcess,0),C.Adjusted) AS Adjusted,
       C.Balance - ISNULL(C.RunningExcess,0) AS Balance,
       C.Excess
FROM CTE C;
```